# Java Explicit Declaration in Multi Dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to explicitly declare values in a multidimensional array.
I keep getting a multitude of error messages

Here is the offending code:

```
    int[][] test = new int [6][3];
    test[0] = {1,2,3};
    test[1] = {1,3,2};
    test[2] = {2,3,1};
    test[3] = {2,1,3};
    test[4] = {3,2,1};
    test[5] = {3,1,2};
```

Is this not allowed in 2 dimensional arrays?
  I have read the java doc on arrays

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: error ']' expected, error: illegal start of expressions, error illegal start of expression and error not a statement for the 2nd line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int [][] test = {
        {1,2,3},
        {1,3,2},
        {2,3,1},
        {2,1,3},
        {3,2,1},
        {3,1,2}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You had wrong syntax. You have to specify what to instantize.

```
int[][] test = new int [6][3];
test[0] = new int[]{1,2,3};
test[1] = new int[]{1,3,2};
test[2] = new int[]{2,3,1};
test[3] = new int[]{2,1,3};
test[4] = new int[]{3,2,1};
test[5] = new int[]{3,1,2};
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, I've spend an inordinately large amount of time on this problem

Comment: Additionally if the OP does it this way, they do not need to initialize the second dimension of the array as [3]. They can initialize the array to `new int[6][]` as the receding lines initialize those elements.